# How to solve the recurrence relation $f(1,n)=n+2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Given the following information:
$f(0,n)= n+1$ $ \ \ $ $\forall n$
$f(m,0)=f(m-1,1)$ when $m>0$
$f(m,n)=f(m-1, f(m,n-1))$ when $m>0$ and $n>0$

I have worked out that $f(1,n)=f(0,f(1,n-1))= f(1,n-1) + 1$

But I am unsure of how to get $f(1,n) =n+2$ from this stage ?

Comment: Looks like the Ackermann function.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(1,n) = f(1,n-1) + 1$$

This is an arithmetic progression with $1$ being the difference so $$f(1,n) = f(1,0) + n$$

$$f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 2$$
$$\implies f(1,n) = n+ 2$$

Comment: Why is the second equivalence true ?

Answer (score 1):

You already have:

$$f(1,n)=f(1,n-1) + 1$$
Notice $f(0,1)=f(1,0)=2$, and this is because

$f(0,n)= n+1$, and you let $n=1$, you get $f(0,1)= 2$

$f(m,0)=f(m-1,1)$, and you let $m=1$, you get $f(1,0)=f(0,1)$

Thus $f(1,0)=f(0,1)=2$

Let $a_n=f(1,n)$
So you have $a_n=a_{n-1}+1$, and $a_0=2$

Then

$$a_n=(a_n-a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) + \ldots +(a_1-a_0)+a_0=n+ 2$$

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help but you are not addressing my question. I already know this information.

Comment: @aprilanalysis I'm guessing where you might get stuck, and edited the answer accordingly. Hopefully this is a right guess.

Comment: @aprilanalysis you are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(1,0)=f(0,1)=2 \\
f(1,1)=f(0,f(1,0))=f(0,2)=3 \\
f(1,2)=f(0,f(1,1))=f(0,3)=4 \\
\ddots
\end{eqnarray*}